# How to send push notifications using AWS SNS service to android in NODE JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SNS service to send notifications to mobile app.
I have created a Platform Application, and then added an Application Endpoint based on the device token which I generated through FCM (for android).
Now, I am trying to send a push notification to the that device (application endpoint). I tried to publish via AWS SNS console and it worked.
My aws-sdk version is V3.

Now, I want to do it using Node JS. Following is the code:

File notifications.js:

```
const { SNSClient, PublishCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sns");

// Set the AWS region
const region = process.env.AWS_SNS_REGION";
// Create SNS service object
const sns = new SNSClient({ region });

async function sendPushNotification(sns, params) {
    return await sns.send(new PublishCommand(params));
}

/**
 * Function to publish a push notification to specific user
 * @param {*} message
 * @param {*} endpointARN
 */
async function PublishPushNotification(message, endpointARN) {
    // format message
    message = formatMessage(message?.title, message?.body);
    console.log(message);
    try {
        // Set params
        const publishParams = {
            Message: message,
            TargetArn: endpointARN,
        };
        // Send push notification
        const publishData = await sendPushNotification(sns, publishParams);
        console.log("MessageId is " + publishData.MessageId);
        console.log(publishData);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
    }
}

function formatMessage(title, body) {
    const payload = {
        GCM: JSON.stringify({
            notification: {
                title,
                body,
            },
        }),
    };
    return JSON.stringify(payload);
}

module.exports = {
    PublishPushNotification,
};
```

Calling PublishPushNotification in index.js file.

File index.js

```
const message = {
  title: "BeeMobile",
  body: "Sample message for Android endpoints"
}

const targetArn = process.env.TARGET_ARN;

PublishPushNotification(message, targetArn);
```

It is giving following response:

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: '72aef46b-22e4-5555-a55d-a85163cd1111',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  MessageId: '11224caa-7ab5-57de-9aa5-10514b9c80xr'
}
```

But I am not getting notification on my android device. (When I direct publish through AWS SNS GUI console, it shows the notification)

Can you please let me know where I am making the mistakes?